# When populating drop-down options in a form, it is better to use a filter or request new data?

Tags: javascript, ajax, vue.js

I am performing an `axios` ajax request to my database for a JSON list of `tags` related to a `topic` which is selected using a dropdown. If no `topic` value is passed, then I get a list of every tag in the database (maybe some 100-200 tags at the moment).

The steps are:

1. User selects a `topic` from the downdown
2. Listen for the `onChange` event and pass the value selected to my API using an `axios get()`.
3. Receive the pre-filtered list as a JSON array of objects from the database based on the value sent from `topic`

Obviously every time the user changes the `topic`, another call to the API/Database is made. I have seen (but never used) another option of [filter](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/filters.html)

When designing a form, would it be better to load all the form's option values on `beforeMount()` and then filter them depending on what is selected? Or is waiting until the user selects an option before loading other options a better practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If amount of tags wouldn't grow dramatically I recommend to load them all at once and then just filter them by using a computed prop.